# Pointers of ThreadPool in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on an Android App which makes a lot of HTTP Request.
According what know so far, Android doesn't support to make request from UI thread, so every time I make a HTTP request, I will need to spin a new thread.

However, I don't want to do `new Runnable(...).start()` way everytime, since it cost time to start an thread, and expose a lot of problems of managing multiple threads.

I am thinking to use an `ThreadPool`  to better manage the threads. According to many people, `AsyncTask` is not the best way to solve the problem. So I was wondering if there are some recommend ways to use a generic `ThreadPool` to handle different kinds of request tasks?

Comment: have you had a look at the [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) library yet? It handles all that stuff behind the scenes for you.

Comment: HI @panini thanks for the comment, but I would prefer to use the official libraries to reduce dependencies if possible. Do you have recommendations of what to use in the Android Library?

Comment: in that case AsyncTask + an [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) is probably the right way to go

Comment: FWIW, Volley comes from AOSP + Google Play.  Square has some good libraries too like retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/   No need to reinvent the wheel.